# How to add a product to a collection by ID

Tags: product, collection

Lets say I have an empty collection and a list of productIDs. I want to populate the collection with products specified by the IDs in the list. How would I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to prepare a "Collection" if you have product ID's then this should be fine.

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => array(OF_YOUR_PRODUCTIDS)));
```

In this way you can get the "collection" object, just query it using those IDs.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did:

```
// Get array of IDs from cookie
$productIds = explode(';', Mage::helper('customcompare/cookieAccess')->readCookie());

// Add products to collection
$count=0;
foreach ($productIds as $productId) {
    $newProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
    $collection[$count] = $newProduct;
    $count = $count + 1;
}
```